# How to read context-param values from web.xml with a normal Java class

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I know it it is easy to read the context-param values from web.xml with a Servlet.

But is it possible to read the value with a normal java class?

Comment: Are you going to provide your own servlets spec implementation?

Comment: The web app is mixed with servlets and old style jsp pages. I am trying to make the property java class can read the property file path from web.xml instead of a constant.

Comment: It is possible using File api. But why would somebody want to do it.

Comment: @Roman I donot understand what you mean by my own servlets spec implementation...

Answer (score 4):

You *can* perse web.xml (with something like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/)), but I guess that's not your point - a `context-param` does not make any sense in a non-servlet environment.

I assume you want to obtain the value of an init parameter in a class in your web application that is not a servlet, but is, say, a helper class.

You can - your entry point is always a servlet, so get the `context-param` value there and pass it as a method argument to the method you need.

In case this is configuration that you can afford to make `static` - load it only once, on `init()` of a servlet.

Comment: You are right about the scenario I am facing right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Request object you can get the ServletContext from that and you can get the init parameters from the Context via the API.

Comment: I donot think i have the request object available.:(